# LoggedIn user info show after login on alert dialog

Tags: android

I want to show loggedin user details after while user login to app. It will show via alert dialog. but how to add, where i add that i can't do it. please help me. here is my loginactivity code. nedd how to pass login info to the next activity to show alert dialog.

```
package com.dairy.iconic;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.rudf.library.UpdateChecker;
import static com.dairy.iconic.Iconic.isNetworkStatusAvialable;
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText Name = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText Password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final Button Login = findViewById(R.id.login);

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                validate(Name.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    private void validate(String username, String password) {
        if(
                   (username.equals("1510633101")) && (password.equals("01571728906"))
                || (username.equals("1510533102")) && (password.equals("01762824252"))
                || (username.equals("14077127")) && (password.equals("01722347879"))
                || (username.equals("13027191")) && (password.equals("01558922366"))) 

                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (getString(R.string.login_success)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).cancel();
                } else {

            //User Logged in Failed
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (getString(R.string.login_unsuccess)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use intent to pass next activity intent.put("key","value")

Comment: is user info show with an alert dialog ?

Comment: Yes, after getting value from intent you can pass to alert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an AlertDialog Fragment and then show it. This is the documentation for Dialogs - 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#java

Something like this -

```
public class ShowUserInfo extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage('User information')
               .setPositiveButton('OK', new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     // Do whatever you want to happen when the user presses 'ok'
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Then call it simply by

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new ShowUserInfo();
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "userInfo");
```